# Trailing slash vs no trailing slash NO REDIRECT

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have to be able to direct a GET or POST request when it comes in to

```
/eSCL/ScannerStatus
```

or

```
/eSCL/ScannerStatus/
```

TO

```
/eSCL/ScannerStatus/index.php
```

I am NOT looking for a redirect, as that is what I am getting now. (301 Permanently moved)

It is to say whether trailing slash or not, the request references a directory and I need to load index.php in that directory with NO redirect

I have reviewed the docs here 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html
and quite frankly it does not seem to work as stated or maybe I am missing a mod?

I have tried many variations .

I have run

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and

```
sudo a2enmod dir
```

both now show as enabled.

Apache 2.4 running on Raspberry Pi3

I have tried MANY MANY different rules and I also see in google results that this is a problem for many others trying to do the same. I see numerous "solutions" posted many of which do not work.

I see no reason to ressurect the 20+ mod rewrite attempts that I have made and failed . I am looking for what works without a redirect

Edit-UPDATE-------------------------------------------------

I just got back to this , deleted `.htaccess`, and now server refuses to load `index.php` and shows a directory listing instead.

This leaves me perplexed. I do not believe I need `.htaccess` for PHP files as it was not there before.

EDIT UPDATE 2------------------------------------
I managed to get back on track with some directives that seemed to go away for some reason.

I now have in /var/www/html/.htaccess

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^eSCL/ScannerStatus/?$ eSCL/ScannerStatus/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^eSCL/ScannerCapabilities/?$ eSCL/ScannerCapabilities/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^eSCL/ScanJobs/?$ eSCL/ScanJobs/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^eSCL/Scans/?$ eSCL/Scans/index.php [L]
```

in the global secion of apache2.conf I have (this is apparently what I had to do to get index.php files to load as default again):

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/scans/*">
DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/eSCL/ScannerStatus">
DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/eSCL/ScannerCapabilities">
DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/eSCL/ScanJobs">
DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm
</Directory>
```

Here is what wireshark captures when requesting http://192.168.1.50/eSCL/ScannerStatus (no trailing slash)

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 06 Feb 2020 16:56:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian)
Location: http://192.168.1.50/eSCL/ScannerStatus/
Content-Length: 327
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a 
href="http://192.168.1.50/eSCL/ScannerStatus/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) Server at 192.168.1.50 Port 80</address>
```

I have also specifically excluded the sites-enabled files in apache2.conf with

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
# IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

I have also verified:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2 $ sudo a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2 $ sudo a2enmod dir
Module dir already enabled
```

Comment: Please always show what you have tried. [ask]

Comment: How do you expect us to help with your rewriting rule if you do not post it?

Comment: I have tried MANY rewrite rules. WHat I am looking for is what works. I have already tried many that do not work! All I have tried give me 301 permanently moved.. That is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
/eSCL/ScannerStatus
```

If `ScannerStatus` is a physical directory then by default, mod_dir will append the slash with a 301 redirect in order to "fix" the URL.

You need to override this behaviour and set `DirectorySlash Off`. You will then need to *internally rewrite* the request using mod_rewrite to the desired `index.php` document (instead of relying on `DirectoryIndex` as you would normally).

For example, in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^eSCL/ScannerStatus/?$ eSCL/SCannerStatus/index.php [L]
```

Note that you will need to clear your browser cache as the 301 redirect to append the slash (by mod_dir) will most likely have been cached by the browser.

> I do not believe I need `.htaccess` for PHP files as it was not there before.

You need `.htaccess` if you want to override default server behaviour and use physical directories without trailing slashes.

---

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> <Directory "/var/www/html">
> DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory "/var/www/html/scans/*">
> DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory "/var/www/html/eSCL/ScannerStatus">
> DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory "/var/www/html/eSCL/ScannerCapabilities">
> DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm
> </Directory>
>
> <Directory "/var/www/html/eSCL/ScanJobs">
> DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm
> </Directory>
> ```

The `<Directory>` container applies to the stated directory and all subdirectories. So in the above, all except the first `<Directory "/var/www/html">` container are not required.

However, there's nothing here that is enabling `.htaccess` overrides? And the behaviour you are currently seeing would seem to suggest that `.htaccess` files are not enabled - since the `.htaccess` directives don't appear to be doing *anything*.

*TEST:* Add any "nonsense" to the top of the `.htaccess` file. If `.htaccess` files are being processed then this will break horribly and result in a 500 Internal Server Error. If no error then the `.htaccess` file is being ignored (ie. `.htaccess` files are not enabled).

The *rewrite* we added in `.htaccess` to route requests to `index.php` negates the need for `DirectoryIndex` - but there is no harm adding this.

To enable `.htaccess` overrides you need to set `AllowOverride` in the relevant `<Directory>` container. For example:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
# Allow .htaccess files to override config directives
AllowOverride All

# Allow mod_dir to issue an internal subrequest for the DirectoryIndex
# when requesting /subdirectory/ (note the trailing slash)
DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm

# Access needs to be permitted (somewhere)
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If you have access to the server config then you don't *need* `.htaccess`. All the directives in `.htaccess` (a *directory* context) can go directly in the relevant `<Directory>` container. (Although development/distribution requirements could make the use of `.htaccess` files easier.)

Incidentally, the `DirectoryIndex` directive can be used in `.htaccess`.

---

*Aside:*

As noted earlier, the above rewrite in `.htaccess` negates the need for `DirectoryIndex index.php`. However, they can be modified *slightly* to make use of this. For example (an academic excercise):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

# Note the different regex having removed "/?"
RewriteRule ^eSCL/ScannerStatus$ eSCL/SCannerStatus/index.php [L]
```

Now, a request for `/eSCL/ScannerStatus` (no trailing slash) is rewritten using mod_rewrite to `index.php`. But a request for `/eSCL/ScannerStatus/` (with a trailing slash) is now handled by `DirectoryIndex` which returns `index.php` via an internal subrequest. With the earlier `RewriteRule`, both these requests were handled by mod_rewrite.

Note that the 4 rules for the 4 different sub-subdirectories can potentially be combined into a single rule.

Comment: MrWhite I did all that and wireshark still shows that Apache sends "Moved Permanently 301". Either there is something I need install or configure or that method does not work. I assume I should be able to add additional RewriteRule lines below the first in your example.

Comment: Are `.htaccess` files enabled? What is the redirect you are seeing? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path. The code I posted above is all that's required, providing mod_rewrite and mod_dir are enabled and overrides for `.htaccess` are allowed. And you have no other conflicting directives in your server config or other `.htaccess` files.

Comment: It looks like your `.htaccess` file is being ignored (ie. `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled)? `.htaccess` files are not enabled by default on Apache 2.4 and must be explicitly enabled in the server config. I've updated my answer.

Comment: MrWhite, Thanks for this will test adding 

<Directory "/var/www/html">
# Allow .htaccess files to override config directives
AllowOverride All

# Allow mod_dir to issue an internal subrequest for the DirectoryIndex
# when requesting /subdirectory/ (note the trailing slash)
DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm

# Access needs to be permitted (somewhere)
Require all granted
</Directory>

To apache2.conf